# Django | Error al convertir ForeignKey en ManyToMany

Tags: django, django-models

Como ForeignKey funciona bien, pero al querer convertir "actuacion" en ManyToMany me devuelve el siguiente error:

**Error:**

```
<class 'actuacion.admin.ActuacionAdmin'>: (admin.E109) The value of 'list_display[4]' must not be a ManyToManyField.
```

**Archivo:** models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from dispositivo.models import Dispositivo
from consumible.models import Consumible
from incidencia.models import Incidencia
from fallo.models import Fallo

class TipoActuacion(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Nombre',max_length=50,null=True,blank=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Tipo actuación'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Tipos de actuaciones'
        ordering = ['name']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

# Create your models here.
class Actuacion(models.Model):
    actuacion = models.ManyToManyField(TipoActuacion)
    resumen_actuacion = models.TextField('Resumen',null=True, blank=True)

    class meta:
        verbose_name = 'Incidencia'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Incidencias'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.resumen_actuacion
```

Answer (score 1):

No puedes colocar directamente un ManyToManyField en el list_display, puedes crear un método que le de formato al contenido, por ejemplo en tu admin agrega algo como esto:

```py
class ActuacionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...
    list_display = ('resumen_actuacion', 'get_actuacion')

    def get_actuacion(self, object):
        return ", ".join([actuacion.name for actuacion in object.actuacion.all()])
```

El código no está probado, pero debería funcionar con pequeñas modificaciones.

Comment: Gracias Marcelo. Me devuelve: def get_actuacion(self.object): SyntaxError: invalid syntax (indicándome con el síbolo ^ el punto entre self y object). Un saludo.

Comment: @julian se confundió, el punto debe ser una coma xD

Comment: El punto debe ser una coma como dice @JulioCesar